# Parsing JSON response in JAVA

Tags: json

I have a standard java http client. I am receiving a JSON response while invoking an HTTP operation.

The response looks like as below :

```
//OK[25,24,23,22,21,20,19,8,8,8,8,8,18,17,16,15,14,8,13,12,11,10,9,9,8,8,8,7,4,6,5,4,3,2,34,1,["[Ljava.lang.String;/2600011424","17501-20000-39010","1152963","Not Available","Open","2222","01/15/2012","0.00","1663.07","02/09/2012","02/15/2012","4446.36","2783.29","2038.71","02407.65","03/11/2012","486.76","07135.7900","0","01/26/2012","001122 AAA BBB CCC","1","Y","01/23/2012","E"],0,5]
```

Though the content type is application/json in the response, I am not sure on how to process this JSON format.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: But the HTTP response header Content-Type says application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: @user1173245 — The server lies.

Comment: If you can strip the non-JSON parts from that response you might then try to parse the remaining JSON using one of the many parsing frameworks like gson, json-simple etc.

Comment: This one looks GWT RPC not JSON

Comment: @user1173245 If I was the server I could also tell you the content type is `application/msword` :)

Comment: @Henrique Miranda Thanks for the clue. It indeed looks like GWT RPC. Any ideas on how to deserialize this GWT RPC response ?

Answer (score 2):

Check [JSON in Java](http://json.org/java/). Should be pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't actually JSON, but if you strip off the `//OK` from the front then it would be.

Strip through characters then run it through a JSON parser. Several are listed just after the diagrams on the [JSON homage](http://json.org/).